# Software to assist with validating files against a schema and automatically generate files from database

Tags: database, validation, schema

A company I am working for currently uses BizTalk to gather data from their database and put it into the desired format (EDI X12 834), which is an extremely regulated format that must be created perfectly. Some of the problems with using BizTalk are that it only loosely validates if the file is in the correct schema. So my company is looking for a software product to perform a similar operation, but is capable of being much more thorough in its creation and validation of a file matching the schema.

Does anyone have any recommendations? I am very new to the company and have little information to go off, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd

Having 10 years of experience with BizTalk (versions 2003 to 2013)
Prober edifact XML schema validation wasn't a problem

You might have local versions which differs from the offical releases
Make sure to duplicate and adjust your schemas accordingly